# Memory efficiency of each versus reduce/inject in Ruby

Tags: ruby, memory-management, each, reduce, inject

I have a large array (10+ million objects) that I want to combine into a single object (for simplicity, let's assume here a string) and run each element in the array through some processing (abstracted by the function `do_stuff`). There are two natural ways to do this:

```
memo = ""
big_array.each do |e|
  memo << do_stuff(e)
end
memo
```

and

```
big_array.reduce("") do |memo, e|
  memo + do_stuff(e)
end
```

The reduce/inject syntax is more aesthetically appealing, but the question is which is more *memory* efficient. We already know that [each is marginally more time efficient than reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679941/ruby-map-reduce-function-necessarily-efficient), but what about memory?

I'm also not clear on how I could profile memory usage in Ruby, especially over just a block of code, so if someone can provide some pointers to that I would also appreciate it.

Comment: I think it depends a lot on what `memo` is. Here, in the first case, string is mutated and you don't create a new instance in every iteration, as you do in the second example.

Comment: In your second example you could also use `<<` instead of `+` (although `each_with_object` would be better choice then). In current shape I'm pretty sure that latter is much worse in terms of memory consumption (especially if `memo` tends to grow large).

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that with map reduce (as written in your example) you are creating a new string each time `+`).

Using `<<` you are modifying the original string. This should be better as less GC cycles will be triggered.

You mentioned that you are using a string as an example; so it's difficult to answer for your real problem.